# hang in duplex c# signalr client

Tags: signalr

somebody reported a similar issue. Its not clear what the resolution was

I have code that might invoke a response while a method is being invoked

```
                    proxy.On<string, byte[], int>("Foo", (connId, data, seq) => 
                        {
                            DoFoo();
                        });
```

DoFoo usually ends up invoking a response to the same client but on a different thread. This response call ends up hanging in its invoke.Wait() after a few messages.

If I do

```
                    proxy.On<string, byte[], int>("Foo", (connId, data, seq) => 
                        {
                            System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((x)=>
                                {
                            DoFoo(connId, data, seq);
                                });
                        });
```

Things get a lot better. I have had one or 2 hangs but only under extreme load, but its still doesnt seem right. ie work 95% is better that work 20%, but 95% is not perfect

This is signalr 2.1.2

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this. I'm having the same problem, hanging about 99 % of the time but sometimes not.